# Excluir registros sem atualizar página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

Estou tentando excluir registros sem ter que atualizar a página, porém não estou tendo sucesso, os registros apagam mas a tabela só atualiza se der um F5, estou tentando fazer isso via ajax mas não está rolando, alguém consegue me dar uma luz?
Aqui eu tenho o botão de excluir o registro e passo o id

```
<li>
   <a onclick="excluirLancamento(<?= $user->id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excluir</a>
```

E aqui o javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function excluirLancamento(id) {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?')) {
        $.ajax({async:true, type:'post', 
            complete:function(request, json) {
                $('#caixa').html(request.responseText); 
                excluirTr('registro'+id);
            }, 
            url:'/users/delete/'+id
        }); 
    } else { return false; }
}
```

lembrando que estou importando corretamente o jquery

```
<script src="/webroot/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: O problema seria na função ` excluirTr('registro'+id);` que não esta excluindo as linhas da tabela em html?

Comment: Ela exclui a linha, mas tenho que dar um F5 para atualizar a tabela, gostaria que não precisa-se atualizar, não sei está correto a maneira que estou fazendo isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa atribuir um ID pra cada linha de lançamento. Após o retorno do Ajax, essa ID é removida.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function excluirLancamento(id) {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?')) {
        $.ajax({async:true, type:'post', 
            complete:function(request, json) {
                $('#caixa').html(request.responseText); 
                excluirTr('registro'+id);

                $("#linha"+id).remove(); //remove a linha do registro ou lançamento
            }, 
            url:'/users/delete/'+id
        }); 
    } else { return false; }
}
```

Atualização:

Coloca uma ID pra cada `<TR>`. Por exemplo:

```
<tr id="linha<?= $user->id ?>">
```

No script você irá excluir a `<TR>` com o ID: "linha"+id. Modifiquei o javascript acima tb.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwgt51fx/

Comment: Olá David, fiz da forma que mencionou, ela exclui mas continuo tendo que atualizar a página para remover o registro

Comment: @Henrique Coloca uma amostra do código todo. Da forma que vc está querendo saber fica difícil de ajudar. Só pra saber: uma das principais vantagens em usar Ajax é não ter que atualizar a página. Deve ter alguma coisa errada no seu código. Posta ele aí pra gente ver.

Comment: David, vai ser complicado de por todo código aqui, disponibilizei para vc ver nesse link aqui, https://bitbucket.org/ORique/ajax desde já agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: @Henrique Você tá usando tabela <table> para cada lançamento a ser excluído?

Comment: Isso, os registros estão dentro de uma table

Comment: @Henrique Dá uma olhada no update que botei.

Comment: @Henrique Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pwgt51fx/

Comment: O vlw de novo...hahaha
Assim que possível vou testar mas acredito que não vai ter erro, qualquer coisa eu dou um grito, mais uma vez obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Olá, se os registros apagam, basta colocar uma função para excluir a parte "visual" no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function excluirLancamento(id) {
    if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir este registro?')) {
        $.ajax({async:true, type:'post', 
            complete:function(request, json) {
                $('#caixa').html(request.responseText); 
                excluirTr('registro'+id);

                // aqui a função que deleta visualmente.
                $('#user').remove();
            }, 
            url:'/users/delete/'+id
        }); 
    } else { return false; }
}
```

No seu html:

```
  <a id="user" onclick="excluirLancamento(<?= $user->id ?>)"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excluir</a>
```

Comment: Olá Lucas, fiz da forma que mencionou, ela exclui mas continuo tendo que atualizar a página para remover o registro

Comment: Tente colocar a linha: ('#user').remove();  em uma função separada! Também é importante colocar o id junto com o id no html e no remove! Para excluir apenas aquele <a> desejado!

Comment: Henrique, no caso de ter que atualizar a página para remover o registro, acontece que o AJAX ainda não terminou de fazer as requisições e por isso essa necessidade. Uma alternativa seria criar uma função apenas para colocar o ('#user'+id).remove() e chamar essa função junto com o onclick do ajax!

Comment: Também não resolveu, putz não sei qual erro estou cometendo

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer usando uma **iframe(hidden)** que atualiza quando você apaga o registro ... e fazer ela dar refresh sem ter que atualizar a página por completo.